# UITableViewController Delegate and DataSource method not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am quite new in ios dev and i am trying to populate table view using Array of HCPerson class. I am also playing around with bring object created in nib to storyboard by code. But no matter what i do the table doesn't become populated

```
#import "HCTableViewController.h"
NSString *const HCTableCellNibName=@"HCTableCell";
NSString *const HCCellIdentifier=@"personCell";
@interface HCTableViewController()

@end
@implementation HCTableViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:HCTableCellNibName bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:HCCellIdentifier];

}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.persons.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell=(UITableViewCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HCCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    HCPerson *person=self.persons[indexPath.row];

    [self configureCell:cell forPerson:person];
    return cell;

}

-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell forPerson:(HCPerson*)person
{
    cell.textLabel.text=person.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] stringFromNumber:person.age];
}
@end

//HCPerson
#import "HCPerson.h"

@interface HCPerson()

@end
@implementation HCPerson
+(HCPerson*)personWithName:(NSString*)name age:(NSNumber*)age residence:(NSString*)residence contact:(NSString *)contact
{
    HCPerson *newPerson=[[self alloc] init];

    newPerson.name=name;
    newPerson.age=age;
    newPerson.residence=residence;
    newPerson.contact=contact;

    return newPerson;
}
@end
```

EDIT: Karthik solved this using UIViewController with outleting TableView from it. But is there any way to call the delegate and datasource method using UITableViewController

Comment: where you added the object in your model class

Comment: App delegate applicationdidfinishlaunching

Comment: Did you try and debug whether the delegate and datasource methods are being called ?

Comment: delegate methods are called but i couldn't see anything when i put NSLog in datasource methods

Comment: That means your datasource method are not being called.

Comment: what should i do then?\

Answer (score 1):

ok lets try on your viewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:HCTableCellNibName bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:HCCellIdentifier];

 if ( self.persons.count>0)
{
[self.yourtableview reloadData];
}
else
{
// no data found , put the NSLog and print the count

}
```

ok **choice no-2**

try this

```
UITableViewCell* cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HCCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Remove that self because it show be kept of that method. Not your `Tableview` and also try with different name than `tableView` because `Xcode` finds it difficult to select one from them.

Comment: if ( self.persons.count>0) is true with count=4 but still no data in tableview

Comment: check the updated answer bro, another one put the breakpoint in `numberOfRowInSection` and check the datasource method is called or not

Comment: else add this method in `[self.yourtableview reloadData];` in `ViewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add table view controller from storyboard?
If yes, Go to storyborad -> Inspector Area ->File Inspector - add your class name there.

[Screenshot attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrDzE.png)